# Get email folder from MailItem via MAPI interface

Tags: c#, outlook-2007, office-interop, mapi

I'm creating a program to automatically generate reports from incoming email attachments and it is almost complete save for one area. The incoming emails are automatically filtered into folders which differentiate which client and server they originate from. I can't figure out how to get the path of the folder from the email Item.

I'm using the `NewMailEx` event to call the method below and `this.AppNamespace` and `this.ReportFolder` are confirmed to be instantiated properly.

```
void AppClass_NewMailEx(string EntryIDCollection)
{
    Outlook.MailItem Item = (Outlook.MailItem)this.AppNamespace.GetItemFromID(EntryIDCollection, this.ReportFolder.StoreID);
    string FolderName = ""; //How do I get this?
}
```

The MSDN on `MailItem` is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem_members.aspx). Am I missing something or approaching this the incorrect way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there's a Parent that you can check - it should return a MAPIFolder that you can check the Name of.

Comment: There is a `Parent` property however the documentation is basically non-existent on what it actually returns. I'll give it a try here shortly.

Comment: I'm assuming it returns an `object` because the context of the mail item parent might not be a folder. For example, right clicking on a IPM.Note in your inbox should return a `Folder` as a parent, however if you're in the compose view the parent might be the inspector or null (haven't tried it).